# How to scp from private server to Amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos7

I need to copy files from server A to S3.

**Constraints:**

1. A is in the private only network.
2. A can only be ssh from B.

**What I Tried:**
`scp -i key.pem user@ip:/path/to/file >(aws s3 cp - s3://s3/uri)`
This command copied the file from A to s3 only if the file name is `-`.

Any names other than `-` is giving an error:
`The user-provided path file does not exist.`

Comment: The string `-` is a synonym for stdin in this case.

Comment: not clear what you're trying to achieve by changing `-` to some other name

Comment: I was trying to name the file getting created in s3. @GypsyCosmonaut

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my bad.
I thought `-` as the name of the source file.
Because when I tried to send files with just `s3://s3/uri` it copied file with a name `-`.

Instead `-` represents the stdin that is passed to aws cli using bash's process substitution `<()`.
Now, copying files by changing my cmd in qn like this:
`scp -i key.pem user@ip:/path/to/file >(aws s3 cp - s3://s3/uri/filename)`.